# find common class for all objects in a collection

Tags: java

I have a function:

```
void foo(Collection<? extends Baz> messages) {
```

How do I determine the most-derived common subclass for all elements in the collection?

It may be that all elements extend `Bar`, which extends `Baz`.  Some might extend `Fuz`, which extends `Bar`, but not all; in that case, the most-derived common subclass would still be `Bar`.

Comment: Question is unclear. Are you looking to see if all objects in the collection are instances of a common class beneath Baz in the class hierarchy? Or are you lookin just so see what class beneath Baz is the most common, without requirement for all objects to instantiate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate the collection and transform each element to the list of classes in their hierarchy (eg `Fuz`-`Bar`-`Baz`-`Object`).

For each following element, `classList.retainAll()` the result of the same operation.

Take the first element of the resulting list.

EDIT:

Since you marked this as answering your question, I'll actually put in some more work.

Here's how I would write it:

```
public static Class mostDerived(Collection<?> objects) {
    Optional<List<Class<?>>> mostDerived =
        objects.stream()
               .map(Util::getHierarchy) // class list for each
               .reduce((l1, l2) -> {
                   l1.retainAll(l2); // get intersecting classes
                   return l1;
               });
    return mostDerived.map(l -> l.get(0)).orElse(null);
}

private static List<Class<?>> getHierarchy(Object l) {
    List<Class<?>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Class<?> clz = l.getClass(); clz != null; clz = clz.getSuperclass()) {
        result.add(clz);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Here's it running](https://ideone.com/GokBsw) with your test cases.

Comment: this approach seems to work!   A quick implementation and test https://gist.github.com/williame/158fcb90332074eb8854682fdb8d68df

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to be able to check for some specific cases, if all messages are of a certain type.

If that is the case, just go for:

```
if(messages.stream().allMatch(i -> i instanceof SomeObject)) {
     ...
}
```

Otherwise you could write a nested search using the reflection API perhaps... but that will quickly become very ugly I think.

Comment: This doesn't completely solve OP's problerm: he needs the **lowest** subclass common to all elements in the collection. Testing one of them doesn't cut it.

Comment: The lowest subclass is `Baz`, because `messages` is defined to always extend Baz.  I think he wants to find some specific 'higher' class that is shared. But such a thing doesn't make a lot of sense generically. Only if you have plans to do something with these specific classes, in that case: test for it.

Comment: **Sub**class, not **Super**class. He could have a collection entirely made of `class SubBaz extends Baz` which would make his lowest common subclass `SubBaz`, not `Baz`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that I have been able to come up with, that returns you the closest ancestors of a collection of objects:

```
static Class<?> getCommonAncestor(Collection<?> messages) {
    return messages.stream().map(Object::getClass)
        .collect(Collectors.reducing(Main::getCommonAncestor))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("The collection is empty!"));
}

// this method gets the closest common ancestor between 2 classes
static Class<?> getCommonAncestor(Class<?> a, Class<?> b) {
    Stack<Class<?>> aParents = getParents(a);
    Stack<Class<?>> bParents = getParents(b);

    Class<?> commonAncestor = null;

    // I decided to search from the top of the inheritance tree because i know that
    // there will be the same number of classes on top of a common ancestor
    // I feel like there is a faster way, but I can't think of it...
    while (!aParents.isEmpty() && !bParents.isEmpty()) {
        Class<?> aPopped = aParents.pop();
        Class<?> bPopped = bParents.pop();
        if (aPopped == bPopped) {
            commonAncestor = aPopped;
        }
    }
    return commonAncestor;

}

// this method gets the whole inheritance tree of a single class
static Stack<Class<?>> getParents(Class<?> c) {
    Class<?> clazz = c;
    Stack<Class<?>> parents = new Stack<>();
    parents.push(clazz);
    while (parents.peek() != Object.class) {
        parents.push(clazz.getSuperclass());
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return parents;
}
```

That is the most general case, so it will also work for your `Baz`es and `Bar`s.

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of subclasses `predefinedClassList`, sorted in ascending order (least to most subclassy), which is available at runtime:

```java
for (Baz b : messages) {

   predefinedClassList.stream()
      .filter(c -> messages.stream()
         .allMatch(m -> m.getClass().instanceOf(c)))
      .reduce((a, b) -> b).orElse(Baz.class));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> Class<? extends T> getMostCommonParent(Collection<T> messages) {
    Map<Class<?>, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (T message : messages) {
        Class<?> cls = message.getClass();

        while (cls != Object.class) {
            map.compute(cls, (key, total) -> Optional.ofNullable(total).orElse(0) + 1);
            cls = cls.getSuperclass();
        }
    }

    Class<?> cls = messages.iterator().next().getClass();

    while(map.get(cls) != messages.size())
        cls = cls.getSuperclass();

    return (Class<? extends T>)cls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go through each object, and get all of the classes.

```
List<Class<?>> getClasses(Object o){
    List<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
    Class<?> c = o.getClass();
    while(c!=null){
        classes.add(c);
        c = c.getSuperClass();
    }
    return classes;
}
```

Creating your collection of lists.

```
List<List<Class<?>> allClasses = messages.stream().map(
                                    this::getClasses
                                 ).collect(
                                    Collectors.toList()
                                 );
Set<Class<?>> union = new HashSet<>(allClasses.get(0));
allClasses.forEach(union::retainAll);
```

At this point union has all of the classes that are common. To find the most specified one... I would do a loop over the first list in `allClasses` and then find the first element.

```
Optional<Class<?>> mostSpecified = allClasses.get(0).filter(
                                        union::contains
                                   ).findFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find all common superclasses and then take the one at the bottom of the hierarchy. This does not take interfaces into account, however:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Collection<Object> messages = Arrays.asList(
            new Bar(), new Foo());

    final Set<Class<?>> commonSuperclasses = messages.stream()
            .map(c -> c.getClass())
            .map(c -> getSuperclasses(new HashSet<>(), c))
            .reduce(Sets::intersection) // guava
            .orElse(Collections.emptySet());

    final Class<?> mostSpecificCommonSuperclass =
            commonSuperclasses
                    .stream()
                    .filter(
                            // take the one at the bottom of the hierarchy
                            c -> commonSuperclasses
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(s -> s.getSuperclass())
                                    .noneMatch(c::equals))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(null);

    System.out.println(mostSpecificCommonSuperclass); // prints Bar
}

static Set<Class<?>> getSuperclasses(final Set<Class<?>> acc, final Class<?> clazz) {
    if (clazz == null) {
        return acc;
    }

    return getSuperclasses(Sets.union(acc, Collections.singleton(clazz)), clazz.getSuperclass());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach for this with pure `Stream`, **recursively browse class until the root Baz class**, and with `groupingBy` we can get `Class` stats **distributions**, example:

```
public static Map<Class, Long> foo(Collection<? extends Baz> messages) {
    return messages.stream()
        .map(Object::getClass)
        .distinct()
        .flatMap(i -> getParentClazzs(i, Baz.class))
        .filter(i -> !Objects.equals(i, Baz.class))
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())
        );
}

private static Stream<Class> getParentClazzs(Class clazz, Class<Baz> rootClass) {
    if (Objects.equals(clazz, rootClass)) {
        return Stream.of(clazz);
    }

    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(clazz), getParentClazzs(clazz.getSuperclass(), rootClass));
}
foo(Arrays.asList(new Bar(), new Foo(), new Bar(), new C(), new D()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println(i.getKey().getSimpleName() + " " + i.getValue()));
```

output:
C -> Bar -> Baz

D -> Bar -> Baz

Foo -> Baz

> C 1
>
> D 1
>
> Foo 1
>
> Bar 3